# How can I make this custom filter work in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a custom template take to perform a split function on a form value where I am sending two arguements - the PK and the name .

EX.

```
  value="{{it.pk}} {{it.name}}"
```

Values shown would be something like: 43 mark the 2nd

This is my code below:

```
   @register.filter_function
   def split(item,args):
       args = args.split(item)
       return args[1]
```

So in my template I want to put {{item|spit:" "}} to get the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the rest of the text bits after the split:

```
@register.filter_function
def split(text, split_by):
    return split_by.join(text.split(split_by)[1:])
```

If I get your desire right:

```
>>> split('43 mark the 2nd', ' ')
'mark the 2nd'
>>>
```